# Как сделать чтобы змейка саму себя не ела?

Tags: python-3.7

Как сделать чтобы змейка саму себя не ела если движение вправо то нельзя влево если вверх то нельзя вниз и т.д

```
from tkinter import *
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SEG_SIZE = 20
IN_GAME = True



def create_block():
    global BLOCK
    posx = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (WIDTH-SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE)
    posy = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (HEIGHT-SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE)
    BLOCK = c.create_oval(posx, posy,posx+SEG_SIZE, posy+SEG_SIZE,fill="red")


def main():
    global IN_GAME
    if IN_GAME:
        s.move()
        head_coords = c.coords(s.segments[-1].instance)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = head_coords
        if x2 > WIDTH or x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or y2 > HEIGHT:
            IN_GAME = False
        elif head_coords == c.coords(BLOCK):
            s.add_segment()
            c.delete(BLOCK)
            create_block()
        else:
            for index in range(len(s.segments)-1):
                if head_coords == c.coords(s.segments[index].instance):
                    IN_GAME = False
        root.after(100, main)
    else:
        c.create_text(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2,text="GAME OVER!",font="Arial 20",fill="red")


class Segment(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.instance = c.create_rectangle(x, y,x+SEG_SIZE, y+SEG_SIZE,fill="white")


class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self, segments):
        self.segments = segments
        self.mapping = {"Down": (0, 1), "Right": (1, 0),"Up": (0, -1), "Left": (-1, 0)}
        self.vector = self.mapping["Right"]

    def move(self):
        for index in range(len(self.segments)-1):
            segment = self.segments[index].instance
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[index+1].instance)
            c.coords(segment, x1, y1, x2, y2)

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[-2].instance)

        c.coords(self.segments[-1].instance,x1+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y1+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE,x2+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y2+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE)

    def add_segment(self):
        last_seg = c.coords(self.segments[0].instance)

        x = last_seg[2] - SEG_SIZE
        y = last_seg[3] - SEG_SIZE

        self.segments.insert(0, Segment(x, y))

    def change_direction(self, event):
        if event.keysym in self.mapping:
            self.vector = self.mapping[event.keysym]


root = Tk()
root.title("TestSnake")


c = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#003300")
c.grid()

c.focus_set()
segments = [Segment(SEG_SIZE, SEG_SIZE),Segment(SEG_SIZE*2, SEG_SIZE),Segment(SEG_SIZE*2, SEG_SIZE)]
s = Snake(segments)

c.bind("<KeyPress>", s.change_direction)

create_block()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Уроборос получается что-ли?)

Comment: Извините, что-то накотило на меня ((9(

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в класс Snake поле, где будет храниться вектор запрещенного направления. В функции `move` устанавливайте его как вектор, противоположный направлению движения. В функции `change_direction` проверяйте, совпадает ли новый вектор с запрещенным, и изменяйте `vector` только если они **не** совпадают.

```
class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self, segments):
        self.segments = segments
        self.mapping = {"Down": (0, 1), "Right": (1, 0),"Up": (0, -1), "Left": (-1, 0)}
        self.vector = self.mapping["Right"]
        self.forbidden = self.mapping["Left"]

    def move(self):
        for index in range(len(self.segments)-1):
            segment = self.segments[index].instance
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[index+1].instance)
            c.coords(segment, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[-2].instance)
        c.coords(self.segments[-1].instance,x1+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y1+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE,x2+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y2+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE)
        self.forbidden = (-self.vector[0], -self.vector[1])

    def add_segment(self):
        last_seg = c.coords(self.segments[0].instance)
        x = last_seg[2] - SEG_SIZE
        y = last_seg[3] - SEG_SIZE
        self.segments.insert(0, Segment(x, y))

    def change_direction(self, event):
        if event.keysym in self.mapping:
            if self.mapping[event.keysym] != self.forbidden:
                self.vector = self.mapping[event.keysym]
```

Может показаться, что проще будет проверять сумму векторов `vector` и нового направления движения прямо в функции `change_direction`, но делать это не стоит: баг проявится, когда змея будет смотреть вверх, а игрок быстро нажмет влево а потом вниз.

Comment: Спасибо но вы пропустили двоеточие во втором if:)

Comment: @ToujaKonea Спасибо, поправил.